# How do I register a custom validator in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I wrote this custom validator:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export function notInSet(theSet: Set<string>): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        const val = control.value;
        if(theSet.has(val))
            return {InSet: true};
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now in my template I have this:

```
    <form #myForm novalidate>
        <input pInputText [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" notInSet="existingNames" #theName="ngModel"/>
        <div *ngIf="!theName.valid" class="text-error">
            Please provide a unique name for this api
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here `existingNames` and `name` are defined the the corresponding ts file.

The problem is that that validator is never called. I feel that I have to register it somewhere, but I'm not really sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `directive` when you are using custom validator for template driven forms, here is a working example on stackblitz which you can go through and implement your functionality, kindly let me know if any doubts!

directive

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  Validator,
  AbstractControl,
  ValidationErrors,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[notInSet]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: NotInSetDirective,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  standalone: true,
})
export class NotInSetDirective implements Validator {
  @Input() notInSet!: Map<string, number>;
  constructor() {}

  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    const val = control.value;
    if (this.notInSet.has(val)) return { InSet: true };
    else return null;
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import 'zone.js';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NotInSetDirective } from './validator.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, NotInSetDirective],
  template: `
    <form #myForm novalidate>
        <input pInputText [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" [notInSet]="existingNames" #theName="ngModel"/>
        <div *ngIf="!theName.valid" class="text-error">
            Please provide a unique name for this api
        </div>
        {{theName.valid | json}}
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  existingNames = new Map([
    ['apples', 1],
    ['bananas', 1],
    ['oranges', 1],
  ]);
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u16uj1?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about something -- in the example you provided you used a stand alone component. When I follow your example, when I put the [notInSet] attribute in my component it says "notInSet attribute is not defined in <input>". It is in the declarations & providers of my AppModule, but I'm not sure how to make it visible in the HTML. I can't add it to providers like you did because if I do I get a "can't add providers unless component is stand alone." So I am still missing one piece -- how do I make it visible in the html template?

Comment: @FraserOrr which version of angular are you using, if you are using less than angular 17 please remove the standalone flag and just add to the declarations array for it to work!